# Google App Engine: How to get the offset of an object

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine

I am using Google App Engine in Python.

In My database, I have some Entity which contain score of user. So I wanted to make a page on the ranking of a particular user. To do that, I need to get the 5 user with the higher score than that user and 5 user with lower score than that user, and also the position of that particular user in the database. I could use the cursor() method to get the encoded cursor. But, I cannot get the 5 Entity before the user's identity and even so, I cannot get the position of the user in the database. Maybe I can use the offset to do the query, but How to get the offset of an Entity?

Comment: could you post the GQL query youre running to get the current user score ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really, really need the user's absolute ranking, you should use the [app-engine-ranklist](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-ranklist/) library. Like SQL databases, App Engine has no intrinsic concept of 'rank', since results can be sorted in multiple ways, so if you need it you will need to implement it yourself.

Alternately, if you only need the users on either side of the user's current rank, see Kevin P's solution.

Answer (score 2):

Why not query the data twice?  Once for users with a higher score, in descending order.  Once for users with a lower score.  Fetch five records in each query.